# Unity Lobby/Relay - joining by code results in error 400 Bad Request

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

as a beginner I am trying to test new Unity Packages - Unity Lobby and Unity Relay  to make multiplayer card game. Quick joining lobby and creating a lobby works fine but I have encountered a problem with joining lobby using Join Code. Here's the code:

```
public async void JoinByCode() {
        string lobbyCode = InputField.text;
        Debug.Log(lobbyCode);           
        Debug.Log("Searching for lobby with code " + lobbyCode + "...");
        // UpdateState ?.Invoke("Searching for lobby with code " + lobbyCode + "...");
        try {

           JoinLobbyByCodeOptions options = new JoinLobbyByCodeOptions();
            
            Lobby lobby = await Lobbies.Instance.JoinLobbyByCodeAsync(lobbyCode, options); //<--- results in error 400 - Bad Request
            Debug.Log(lobby);
            Debug.Log("Joined lobby: " + lobby.Id);
            Debug.Log("Players in lobby: " + lobby.Players.Count);

            //RelayCode
            string joinCode = lobby.Data["joinCode"].Value;           
            Debug.Log("Kod dostępu: " + joinCode);
            JoinAllocation allocation = await Relay.Instance.JoinAllocationAsync(joinCode);

             //obiekt joindata
             _joinData = new RelayJoinData {
                 Key = allocation.Key,
                 Port = (ushort) allocation.RelayServer.Port,
                AllocationID = allocation.AllocationId,
                AllocationIDBytes = allocation.AllocationIdBytes,
                ConnectionData = allocation.ConnectionData,
                HostConnectionData = allocation.HostConnectionData,
                IPv4Address = allocation.RelayServer.IpV4
            };

            _joinData.JoinCode = await Relay.Instance.GetJoinCodeAsync(allocation.AllocationId);

            NetworkManager.Singleton.GetComponent<UnityTransport>().SetClientRelayData(
                _joinData.IPv4Address,
                _joinData.Port,
                _joinData.AllocationIDBytes,
                _joinData.Key,
                _joinData.ConnectionData,
                _joinData.HostConnectionData
            );

            NetworkManager.Singleton.StartClient();

            
            Debug.Log("Found lobby, code: " + joinCode);
            UpdateState?.Invoke("Joining lobby, code: " + joinCode + ", players in lobby: " + lobby.Players.Count);
            MatchFound?.Invoke();

        } catch (LobbyServiceException e) {
            Debug.Log("There's a problem finding lobby, try again. " + e);
        }
    }
```

In general: Join Code is passed from InputField, then to JoinLobbyByCodeAsync, then send player data to server. The problem is with variable lobby - when I am trying to test JoinByCode, it results with error:

```
There's a problem finding lobby, try again. Unity.Services.Lobbies.LobbyServiceException: request failed validation ---> Unity.Services.Lobbies.Http.HttpException`1[Unity.Services.Lobbies.Models.ErrorStatus]: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

and I have no idea how to solve this problem. Yes, I was using Unity Documentation for Lobby and trying to find any info about error 400 in Lobby. I will be really grateful if someone could help me with this problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, in my case the input contained an extra character. Make sure that there are only 6 characters in your variable "lobbyCode" by checking it with lobbyCode.Length. Also make sure that you have activated the Lobby and Relay service in the dashboard.

My post to this problem:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/problem-joining-a-private-lobby-through-lobbycode-joinlobbybycodeasync.1287908/#post-8171102

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).